# how to update data from input fields retrieved from database?

Tags: php

I've been looking for answer to my question, but I could not find one,

I am retrieving data to input fields from db and updating the changed value in the input fields to the db again.

Here are my codes

```
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<form method=\"GET\"  action=\" ".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."\" > ";
echo "<tr><td>ID:</td><td>Company Name</td><td>Date for Service</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>";
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'jobrequestnumber' value =".$row['jobrequestnumber']."></td>"  ; // results in the same jobrequestnumbers
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'requestingcompany' value =".$row['requestingcompany']."></td>"    ;//this too
echo "<td><input type= 'date' name = 'dateforService' value =".$row['dateforService']."></td>"  ;// this one also 
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?jobrequestnumber=".$row['jobrequestnumber']."'>Delete</a></td>"; //too
echo "</form> ";
echo "<td><a href=\"update_request.php?jobrequestnumber='jobrequestnumber'&requestingcompany='requestingcompany'&dateforService='dateforService'\">Update</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

in the a link, I am trying to pass values by referring the names of input fields, but it does not work.!

Would there be other ways or somebody can solve this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the purpose of this?

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid. `<td>` must be a child of a `<tr>`. I'm not sure you can put `<form>` between `<table>` and `<tr>`. The browser has no idea where your forms start and where they end, so it submit the first one.

Comment: It works fine, no matter where the <form> is located at.

Comment: yes, but it not standard as @PetrR. say it could lead to problem down the road

Comment: What exactly `<a href=\"update_request.php?…\">Update</a>` does? Why don't you use `<input type='submit'>` instead?

Comment: That is due to when I use submit, it submits entire values of table, but I only need to update one row that is changed. The a link above is for updating selected row's value

Comment: How is `'jobrequestnumber'` converted into the value of the `<input>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use post instead of get

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>ID:</td><td>Company Name</td><td>Date for Service</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<form method=\"post\"  action=\" ".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."\" > 
<input name=\"id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$row['jobrequestnumber']."\">
"; // added hidden id for update


echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'jobrequestnumber' value =".$row['jobrequestnumber']."></td>"  ; // results in the same jobrequestnumbers
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'requestingcompany' value =".$row['requestingcompany']."></td>"    ;//this too
echo "<td><input type= 'date' name = 'dateforService' value =".$row['dateforService']."></td>"  ;// this one also 
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?jobrequestnumber=".$row['jobrequestnumber']."'>Delete</a></td>"; //too
echo " ";
echo "<td><input name=\"update\" type=\"submit\" value=\"update\"></td>";
echo "</tr></form>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: in this case, wouldn't I need only one name matching with one fields ? I have multiple fields and its names recur.

Comment: what? an which fields are multi which need one matching field. maybe an example of the data you want.

Comment: so when I use while loop, the code above produces more than one field for each <td>

Comment: its your code i am using i only added a button and a hidden value. but i updated the code and moved the row header.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, may I ask why I could not use a link for this ?

Comment: you can but all info show up in browser history. also you did not use variable's for your links. example `requestingcompany='requestingcompany'` should be `requestingcompany='$row['requestingcompany']'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysql_fetch_assoc() not mysql_fetch_array

Comment: it results in the same values